# Why does a precompiled header produce warnings in GCC?

Tags: gcc, gcc-warning, precompiled-headers

I have a header file `MyHeader.hpp` that includes a bunch of header files form an external code project. The header files from the external project throw a lot of warnings, which I don't want to see, because I'm not working on that code.

I have precompiled `MyHeader.hpp` and I have verified that GCC is actually using the precompiled header by moving the original `MyHeader.hpp` file, so that it would not be found if GCC tried to use it instead of the precompiled header file `MyHeader.hpp.gch`. This works and it speeds up the compilation process a little bit (but not as much as I had hoped).

**But:** I am still seeing all the warnings produced by the files from the external code. Why do I see those warnings? I thought that GCC would not actually parse the header files that are precompiled and I've verified that it is using the precompiled header file, so why does it display the warnings from that header file?

Comment: Please post a self-contained example. Something like a template instantiation wouldn't really be part of the precompiled header even if the error points into the precompiled file.